# For Which API call I should use bloc?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, bloc, state-management

I'm new to flutter, I have some questions about bloc and I'm working on small projects to develop skills. Could you help me to know about bloc and improve?

I used bloc on every screen (every API call - GET,POST)

1. From the backend, I'm only getting machineID to select machines - Here I used bloc (Just for machineID I used bloc, Is it okay or just can I call http.get without bloc.
2. For many details from the backend I used bloc - I thought, it is good to use bloc here because I'm getting many details.

For one data I used bloc and for many data I used bloc now my project folder is very big because I used state, event for every API call - 30 API

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not problem, Your project folder is very big will appear in any other state management. You can use bloc for every thing, but I suggest that bloc just using for handle data, when update small UI like: update checkBox, update dropdown, change text, change color..... we should use setState()

Comment: For getting one data from the backend? example - machineID

Comment: yes, it  necessary or not it up to you

Comment: ok I got it....